# How to use Google DNS

Tags: macos, router, dns, google-dns

Me and two other guys share cable using a router. I'm using Mac OS X.

My router IP is 192.168.1.1 and my DHCP IP is 192.168.0.101. When I followed Google's DNS configuration manual, I tried to set my IP to 8.8.8.8 and the DNS server to 8.8.4.4 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not your IP you set, it's the DNS servers. Here is a screenshot of my configuration.

[image]